# I want to store the Data inside the variables with (new Promise)? javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-promise

I want to store the Data inside the variable `storData` and print it to console -

```
const opj = [
  { data : {id: 1 , name : "Emad" }},
  { data : {id: 2 , name : "Ahmad" }},
  { data : {id: 3 , name : "Mazen" }}
  ];


const p = new Promise (resolve => {

  setTimeout(resolve(opj), 300);

});


let storData = [];


p.then(result => {
  //console.log(result);
  storData = [...result];
})

// i need the data outside hear in console:

console.log('storData',storData);
```

I want a simplified explanation so I can learn

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: i need the data outside hear in console log in Variable storData

Comment: p.then works in async way. That is why nothing is shown in console.log(storData). To Fix this move console.log inside p.then callback function

Comment: Move the `console.log` statement inside your `then` block. In this case, `console.log` runs before the promise is resolved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were comfortable with wrapping your code in a  function, you could tag it as [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the result instead.

Though it's essentially syntactic sugar, `async/await` provides an easily recognizable chain of events that might be more familiar to someone just learning, but also makes for (arguably) cleaner code.

```js
const opj = [
  { data : {id: 1 , name : "Emad" }},
  { data : {id: 2 , name : "Ahmad" }},
  { data : {id: 3 , name : "Mazen" }}
];

const p = new Promise (resolve => setTimeout(resolve(opj), 300) );

async function getResult() {
  let result = await p;              //wait for p to resolve
  let storData = [...result];        //process the result
  console.log('storData',storData);  //log it
}

getResult();
```

**As for the "simple explanation"**, imagine you call a friend on the telephone and ask if he can lend you some sugar. He says "Sure! I'll bring it over to your house right now." This is `p`. You've kicked off an action somewhere else, but you have no idea how long it will take.

You can keep going about your day, however you can't use the sugar just yet - you have to wait for your friend to arrive (which is what `.then( ... )` or `await` do).

Logging `storData` outside of `.then( ... )` or without an `await` is the equivalent of hanging up the phone and trying to use the sugar *immediately*, instead of waiting for your friend to arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `console.log` statement inside your then block. In this case, `console.log` runs before the promise is resolved

```
p.then(result => {
  //console.log(result);
  storData = [...result];
  console.log(storData)
})
```

This article on MDN should get you started with understanding Promises - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises